# How to prevent StaleObjectStateException on Query.list()?

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I use Hibernate optimistic locks in my software (via @Version annotation). It works quite well, but sometimes I get StaleObjectStateException while trying to *merely retrieve* some objects from database. How can I prevent Hibernate from throwing these exceptions?

Comment: are you modifying entities concurrently? If yes, then try to avoid that.

Comment: @Scorpion - I'm trying to get object from database without making any changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you change some Object in your Session. Then you execute a query, which flushes the session. Since the object is already changed by somebody else you get the Exception.

Solutions: Difficult. You could loop through the contents of your session before executing the query and print out everything that is dirty, in order to find the object that is causing the trouble.

Comment: I've found entity that causes exception. How can I remove it from session?

Comment: there is a method for that in the Session, but that's most likely not the solution. The question is: why is it there and modified, but not flushed and commited?

Comment: The method to remove an entity from a session is evict. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29